# left join and keep unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, join, dplyr, left-join

I have the following df :

```
t1<-structure(list(Country = c("France", "Spain", "England")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))

t2<-structure(list(Country = c("France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", 
"Spain", "Spain", "England", "England", "England", "England", 
"England", "England", "England", "England"), League = c("Ligue 1", 
"Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 2", "Ligue 2", "Ligue 2", "Liga", 
"Liga", "Liga", "Liga 2", "Liga 2", "Liga 2", "Liga 2", "PL1", 
"PL1", "PL1", "PL1", "PL2", "PL2", "PL2", "PL2"), ID = c("EUR", 
"EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", 
"EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", 
"EUR", "EUR")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

I want to left join the two based on **Country** so that I have every **League** per country. I can't use **multiple="any"** argument in **left_join()** since there are several leagues per country.
The desired output would be this:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Country League 
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 France  Ligue 1
2 France  Ligue 2
3 Spain   Liga   
4 Spain   Liga 2 
5 England PL1    
6 England PL2
```

I'm able to get this result by doing the following but it throws a warning message. Also I'm under the impression that this could be done in a more R friendly way using dplyr.

```
dtl<- dtl %>% 
  left_join(select(t2,Country,League),by=c("Country")) %>% 
  dplyr::distinct(Country,League,.keep_all = T)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Briefly, `t1 %>% left_join(distinct(t2, Country, League), by = "Country")`

Comment: In your specific example, just `distinct(t2)` works fine

Comment: Or `distinct(t2[t2$Country %in% t1$Country, ])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Darren's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76779279/left-join-and-keep-unique-values/76779358#comment135358186_76779279) illustrates, the issue is the duplicate rows in `t2`. Remove those, and you get the desired result:

```
library(dplyr)

left_join(t1, distinct(t2), by = "Country") %>% 
  select(-ID)

# Output:
# A tibble: 6 × 2
  Country League 
  <chr>   <chr>  
1 France  Ligue 1
2 France  Ligue 2
3 Spain   Liga   
4 Spain   Liga 2 
5 England PL1    
6 England PL2
```

Comment: It's a good habit to explicitly specify which columns are joined by. I mean `by = "Country"` should not be skipped.

Comment: @DarrenTsai I agree with you - an oversight by me - oddly though, I went through all of the style guides on the [info page of the r tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info), and none of them specify this (though the example for a different point uses `by = ...`. Maybe something to open a Github Issue about, on the tidyverse style guide? :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired output using dplyr's group_by and summarize functions to combine the leagues for each country. Here's the code to achieve the result without the warning message:

```
library(dplyr)

t1 <- structure(list(Country = c("France", "Spain", "England")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
t2 <- structure(list(Country = c("France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "France", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "Spain", "England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "England", "England"), League = c("Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 1", "Ligue 2", "Ligue 2", "Ligue 2", "Liga", "Liga", "Liga", "Liga 2", "Liga 2", "Liga 2", "Liga 2", "PL1", "PL1", "PL1", "PL1", "PL2", "PL2", "PL2", "PL2"), ID = c("EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR", "EUR")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -21L))

result <- t1 %>% 
  left_join(t2, by = "Country") %>% 
  group_by(Country) %>% 
  summarize(League = toString(unique(League)))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  Country League                      
  <chr>   <chr>                       
1 England PL1, PL2                    
2 France  Ligue 1, Ligue 2            
3 Spain   Liga, Liga 2
```